# Pyttsx3 best property for female voice

Tags: python, properties, text-to-speech, pyttsx3

I need to create the most "realistic" sounding voice for a project using pyttx3. What should the property values be? Rate?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: `engine = pyttsx3.init()
engine.setProperty('rate', 150)
voices = engine.getProperty('voices') 
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[1].id)
` is the thing we are using, but I am trying to thinker with the settings such that the voice sounds more lifelike

Comment: What OS are you using? It makes a difference.

Comment: the os was windows 11